# ASP.NET web app works in localhost but not on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

My ASP.NET web app is working 100% in localhost, but in Azure, one of the pages isn't working. It's displaying this error:

> 500 Internal server error Web server cannot perform this request. Please try again later.

In LogFiles > DetailedErrors it shows nothing helpful to solve this problem. I read some solutions from similar problems on this site, but they not working in my case.

Note: my web app doesn't have a database. The difference between the page that doesn't work and other pages is that it uses a Nuget selectPdf community version.

Comment: by "my asp.net web app is 100% in localhost" do you mean it is working in localhost?  Are you getting a YSOD?  Do you have an exception you can provide that's being blocked due to not being in debug while deployed?  What are the solutions you tried that didn't work?  Are you sure the DLL for selectPdf is being deployed?

Comment: yes 100% working without any error in localhost. DLL for selectPdf is deployed

Comment: I have no idea about YSOD

Comment: We need more information. What your page should do?

Comment: @Dreamer YSOD = Yellow Screen of Death, it's the default ASP.NET error page that contains a red title and black-on-yellow stack trace and also the source-code if available on the server.

Comment: no .. there is no YSOD

Comment: Here is my web app page which one showing error after clicking button . You need to give any website link in text box before click button .

[link] (http://yourcv.azurewebsites.net/WebForm1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the SelectPdf package calls into APIs restricted by the App Service sandbox. Most PDF rendering engines use GDI+, which has most functionality restricted by the Azure App Service sandbox. However, this policy is relaxed on dedicated servers. Scaling up to a dedicated server should resolve this problem (i.e. not the Shared or Free SKU).

Comment: I didn't understand . Why did they restrict it ? Is it illegal or something ..?

Comment: Large portions of the WinAPI are restricted due to security. In a shared hosting environment, it's important to proactively minimize the attack surface. GDI+ uses some of those APIs, hence it will not work, and may cause other things dependent on it to break as well.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when something is working in localhost, but not on Azure after you've deployed it, it's because the Azure box that the code you've deployed to does not have all the dependencies installed that your app needs.  You'll need to go into the console of the machine (inside the management portal or via remote desktop), and install all dependencies required.  Some come native but others need to be manually installed.

Comment: I am really new in azure . How to do it ?